# Google Checkout 0$ recurring payments

Tags: google-checkout, android-pay

We've had a number of customers billed 0$ by Google-handled Checkout recurring payments. Basically in the XML we have sent for these orders, item > subscription > recurrent-item > unit-price was set to 0 (even though the maximum-charge value was correct).

When placing sandbox orders on the customer checkout page, we saw orders displaying the correct amounts, only to later discover on the merchant side that the recurring charges were actually 0.

Is there a way to update recurring subscription items prices such that they are charged the right amount?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your customers will have to purchase new subscriptions, there's not a way to update the existing subscription.